# Robust http client for php-5.6.4

Tags: php, apache, http

What other robust http clients are available for php-5.6.4? i have tried pecl-2.5.1 but have too many issue with trying to use it on my php bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what level of complexity you need. Off the top of my head, there's:

- curl (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)
- for basic stuff you could just use file_get_contents (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
- there's HTTP_Request2 - https://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2.
- Guzzle also looks interesting - http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: thanks for your answer, yes ive been using curl but would like to use something more robust that can handle tens of thousands of requests.

Comment: what's your use case? do you need to do it in php, i.e. do you need to check the return code, handle the response etc.? or do you just need to hit URLs? previously when I've had to hit tens of thousands of URLs (for cachewarming all pages across a large site) I've used php to generate the URLs, poked them into a file & then passed the file to wget, to hit all the URLs. Obviously you lose control of the responses this way

Comment: my use case is to create a browser of some form and then pass in required data multiple times to query a datastore for the correct information this will need to be done a number of times.

Comment: sounds like you do need to retain control then, best take a look at one of those libraries then.

Comment: I can't recommend it as I've never used it, but it looks fun to play around with - give it a go & see how you get on :) if you post a new question with some code and/or examples of the sort of inputs, outputs, expected values etc. from your processes, you'll probably get better suggestions. As it is, your question is a little too conceptual to get much attention (in my opinion)